# Programmatically assigning css classes in React

Tags: css, reactjs, react-css-modules

In my React app I have a set of classes that I am assigning to various elements.  They are named button1, button2, button3, etc.  Currently I am using a switch statement to determine which class to assign.

```
switch (num) {
            case 1:
                return {
                    memberButton: styles.button1
                };
            case 2:
                return {
                    memberButton: styles.button2
                };
            case 3:
                return {
                    memberButton: styles.button3
                };
}
```

Is there a way to assign the class by doing something like this:

```
className={styles.button + rowNumber}
```

Of course that doesn't work.  I'm trying to eliminate the need for a switch statement by constructing the class name in code.

Answer (score 0):

Yo should do it like this:

```
className={styles[`button${rowNumber}`]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approaches

```
<div className={"form-group "+ this.props.errorMessage.roleError ?this.props.errorMessage.roleError : '' +" has-feedback"}></div>
```

another with template literal

```
<div className={`form-group ${this.props.errorMessage.roleError ?this.props.errorMessage.roleError : ''} has-feedback`}></div>
```

in your code

```
className={ styles[`button${rowNumber}`] }
```

or

```
className={styles['button'+rowNumber+'\''] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use brackets to access an Objects hash value using a variable since variables can't be used with dot notation. E.g.:

```
styles = {
  'button1': 'button 1 styles',
  'button2': 'button 2 styles',
  'button3': 'button 3 styles',
}
```

Then you would just do:

```
className={ styles[`button${rowNumber}`] }
```

In short - With dot notation you cannot use variables, but with bracket notation you can.